# Show link only if category has products Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, if

I have code which outputs category images, names and links so that I can use a static block to output all categories within a parent. Currently each image/title is linked even if the category being linked to has 0 products.

**I only want the link to be active if the category it is linking to contains products (i.e. > 0)**. Otherwise there should be no link.

Can anyone please recommend an update to the code below to get this working?

```
    <?php
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $_category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
    $_categories = $_category->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
    ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
    ->joinUrlRewrite();
  ?>

<div class="row mt-10">
        <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <?php Mage::log($_category->debug(), null, 'mylogfile.log'); ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                        <div class="subcat clearfix" style="border:1px solid #333;">
                            <!--<a class="now-from-container" href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>"></a>-->
                            <div class="subcat-image">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>">-->
                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getImageUrl()) ?>" width="690" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="subcat-title-container">
                                <h3 style="background-color:#333;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:10px 0; font-size:22px;"><a style="color:#fff;" href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working using the below code:

```
 <?php
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $_category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
    $_categories = $_category->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
    ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
    ->joinUrlRewrite();
  ?>

<div class="row mt-10">
        <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>                  
                <?php $hasProducts = $_category->getProductCount(); ?>
                <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <?php Mage::log($_category->debug(), null, 'mylogfile.log'); ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                        <div class="subcat clearfix" style="border:1px solid #333;">
                            <?php /* echo $hasProducts */ ?>
                            <!--<a class="now-from-container" href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>"></a>-->
                            <div class="subcat-image">
                                <?php if ($hasProducts > 0) :?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getImageUrl()) ?>" width="690" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
                                    </a>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getImageUrl()) ?>" width="690" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="subcat-title-container">
                                <h3 style="background-color:#333;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:10px 0; font-size:22px; color:#fff;"><!--<a style="color:#fff;" href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>">--><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?><!--</a>--></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this function getProductCount();

```
$hasProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getProductCount();

if($hasProducts > 0 ) {
......
}
else {
.....
}
```

so your final code should look like :

```
<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$_categories = $_category->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
    ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
    ->joinUrlRewrite();
?>

<div class="row mt-10">
    <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <?php $hasProducts = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getProductCount(); ?>
        <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
            <?php Mage::log($_category->debug(), null, 'mylogfile.log'); ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <div class="subcat clearfix" style="border:1px solid #333;">
                    <!--<a class="now-from-container" href="<?php echo // $_category->getURL() ?>"></a>-->
                    <div class="subcat-image">
                        <?php if ($hasProducts > 0) :?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getImageUrl()) ?>" width="690" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
                            </a>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getImageUrl()) ?>" width="690" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subcat-title-container">
                        <h3 style="background-color:#333;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:10px 0; font-size:22px;"><a style="color:#fff;" href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

i have not tested this code yet , but it should work

Comment: I get a blank page currently Naveed... also I think this will show nothing at all if a category has 0 products, but I simply don't want the anchor tag if a category has no products.

Comment: you can place this $hasProducts condtion around your anchor tag, if you want i can update code for you, do you want this anchor tag removed which is with in <div class="subcat-image"> ?

Comment: Hi Naveed that is correct. However, the code you have seems to get the product count from the parent category... rather than for the sub-categories/children. Thank you.

Comment: I have added condition around a tag, you are getting current category and using category/layered model and then its children, so iteration is on current category children from where i picket $_category->getId() which would be children category id in that case and will check if child has products or not and show tag on that basis.

Comment: Hi Naveed... thanks for your hard work, unfortunately I am still getting a blank page...

Comment: its okay no problem, i can't test code since i don't have magento 1.x installed, enable error logs and see what is the error then i might be able to further investigate the issue.. also you can try with echo $hasProducts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75135/discussion-between-yorkiemagento-and-naveed).